# WordPress: How search a post for "post_content" with "wp_query" class?

Tags: wordpress

As the title suggests, I'm trying to find a post through its `post_content`.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Example: `SELECT * FROM DBname WHERE post_content LIKE '%phrase%'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%phrase%'" );
  if ($result){
    foreach($result as $pageThing){
      echo $pageThing->post_content;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ya, give 'er a whirl. Lol, I use something similar for another reason so just chopped it up to use post_content for you. (EDIT: You obviously need to change %phrase% to whatever you're searching for).

Comment: Yes, i'd intended "$wpdb->get_results" and "$pageThing->post_content"

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, (and since it is specified in question) you can achieve this by actually using "WP_Query" class:

```
// The Query
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    's' => 'phrase'
));

// The Loop
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    get_content();
    //...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not entirely correct because this way you're searching the post_title and post_excerpt too: `$search .= $wpdb->prepare( "{$searchand}(({$wpdb->posts}.post_title $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_excerpt $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content $like_op %s))", $like, $like, $like );`