# How to get post by content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get post by content in wordpress, but it looks like i'm getting some random results not linked with query . Any ideas ?

```
$q='my query';
$query = new WP_Query('s = "'.$q.'"');
$gids = array();
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
   $query->the_post();
   $gids[]=get_the_ID();
 }
} else {
    // no posts found
     }
wp_reset_postdata();
//
if (count($gids)>0){
 //find random one 
   $rand = array_rand($gids);
   $post_id=$gids[$rand];
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   header('application/json');
   echo json_encode($post);
 }
```

Comment: might belong to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe, but with over 32,472 wordpress tagged questions here and only 33,293 there, it could equally be argued that it is just as at home here on SO

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this

```
   $args = array(
  'post_content' => 'test',
  'paged' => '1',
  's' => 'post',

 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);

$gids = array();
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
   $query->the_post();
   $gids[]=get_the_ID();
 }
} else {
    // no posts found
     }
wp_reset_postdata();
//
if (count($gids)>0){
 //find random one 
   $rand = array_rand($gids);
   $post_id=$gids[$rand];
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   header('application/json');
   echo json_encode($post);
 }
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working ... But i made it work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677039/wordpress-how-search-a-post-for-post-content-with-wp-query-class

Comment: Its using custom query and i have provided with `WP_Query` but as good  is if your problems solves with custom query then go for it :)